# ASP.net use session data to add something in create view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I created this simple ASP.NET project. (Default template using MVC)

In there I generated models from my database using ADO.net

I also generated controller for my model. (The model generated functions for create, edit, delete...) I also got view for every function in the controller.

So what I am trying to do now is:

-I am in my create view. (that means I see my form for creating objects)
-I need to enter data for [title, content] but to post in database I also need an id (this id is a foreign key, not the id of the object i am creating)

I already have this id saved in my session. I can access the session data by doing:

```
var user = Session["user"] as Uporabniki; //returns session data
user.id //selects id from session
```

Now what I want is to use this id in the create form textbox.

As of now the rows for id in my view look like this (I have no idea why it's a dropdown list. When I open the site I see names of all users in database and I can select one. But this is not what I want. I want to see only one):

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id_avtorja, "id_avtorja", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("id_avtorja", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_avtorja, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

The create methods in controller look like this

```
// GET: Vprasanjas/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.id_avtorja = new SelectList(db.Uporabniki, "id", "uporabniskoIme");            
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Vprasanjas/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,naslov,vsebina,datum,id_avtorja")] Vprasanja vprasanja)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Vprasanja.Add(vprasanja);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.id_avtorja = new SelectList(db.Uporabniki, "id", "uporabniskoIme", vprasanja.id_avtorja);
        return View(vprasanja);
    }
```

Why is it not working if I change the view to something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id_avtorja, "id_avtorja", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @var user = Session["user"] as Uporabniki;
                @Html.Raw(user.id)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_avtorja, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And how can I fix this?

Comment: What kind of error do you see?

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Vprasanja_ToUporabniki\". The conflict occurred in database , table \"dbo.Uporabniki\", column 'id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewrite to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,naslov,vsebina,datum,id_avtorja")] Vprasanja vprasanja)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        vprasanja.id = (Session["user"] as Uporabniki).id;
        db.Vprasanja.Add(vprasanja);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.id_avtorja = new SelectList(db.Uporabniki, "id", "uporabniskoIme", vprasanja.id_avtorja);
    return View(vprasanja);
}
```

Main idea - assign your id on post.

Comment: I like the idea but the problem seems to be somewhere else. Since I keep getting The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error

Comment: try debug and check what value assigning to vprasanja.id object, i think object is empty or you need to fill any other prop id. Can you write here what object going to db.Vprasanja.Add(vprasanja);?

Comment: My bad! Love you dude. It was vprasanja.id_avtorja = (Session["user"] as Uporabniki).id; Best solution! One more question. Someone said it's bad thing to use sessions to post something. Why is that so?

Comment: Don't know why use session is a bad idea. Passing it to view - maybe yes, use it from Session from post - hm, i don't think so. Looks like you a novice in asp.net / mvc, and if yes - it is normal. Best solution is to create separate Business object for your user (you should separate db and business logic, and do not use db entities at view/controller side, it is bad practice), and return it from UserService, for example or BaseController. But you will learn it all during development and reading books/articles. So... Your code is not good, but it is ok for now, while you are learning.

Answer (score 0):

Please post some info on the error. But my guess is you aren't creating any input HTML element so there's nothing posting. You need something like `<input type="hidden" id="id_avtorja" value="@user.id">` in the form.

Also, I'd advise against using data out of a session variable. That's older technology and very un-MVC in philosophy.